# How to provide a default sort on a custom search?

Tags: custom-search

There is a function helper

```
function all($offset = 0, $rowcount = 0, $sort = NULL, $includeContactIDs = FALSE, $justIDs = FALSE) {
  // delegate to $this->sql(), $this->select(), $this->from(), $this->where(), etc.
  return $this->sql($this->select(), $offset, $rowcount, $sort, $includeContactIDs, NULL);
}
```

But I'd like to set a sort order if not set. All the examples I found are writing directly their sql, as opposed to sql() that expect a CRM_Utils_Sort class (or that's what I understand based on the error messages)

So what I'd like to do is to add a

```
if (!$justIDs &&!sort)
   //how to initialise sort so it ends up like ORDER BY created_date)?
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom searches inherit CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_Base; check out the `addSortOffset()` function below (around line 177) to see how the sort is tacked onto the query:

```
public function addSortOffset(&$sql, $offset, $rowcount, $sort) {
    if (!empty($sort)) {
      if (is_string($sort)) {
        $sort = CRM_Utils_Type::escape($sort, 'String');
        $sql .= " ORDER BY $sort ";
      }
      else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . trim($sort->orderBy());
      }
    }
    if ($rowcount > 0 && $offset >= 0) {
      $offset = CRM_Utils_Type::escape($offset, 'Int');
      $rowcount = CRM_Utils_Type::escape($rowcount, 'Int');
      $sql .= " LIMIT $offset, $rowcount ";
    }
  }
```

If you want to use an array it will send it to CRM_Utils_Sort::orderby(). I think you can set your $sort like this:

```
if (!$justIDs &&!sort) {
  $sort = array (
    'name' => 'civicrm_created_date',
    'direction' => 1,
  );
}
```

Would that work for you?