# Default sort field for a Custom Search?

Tags: custom-search

I'm building a custom search and I would like it to have a default sort on (order by) a specific field other than the first field in the list. How can I provide a default sort field?

This stackexchange answer's method doesn't seem to be valid anymore, as it seems the $sort variable is now a non-empty object on initial load of my custom search:

[How to provide a default sort on a custom search?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/how-to-provide-a-default-sort-on-a-custom-search)

Any way to set a default sort column with the newer version of the code?

Comment: You could always use the data processor extension which allows you to build custom searches with a sort

Comment: @AndyClark, unfortunately, I tried that extension (still have it installed) and it has several bugs that are bigger issues than sorting for my use case (I've put a few bug reports to help out the developer with some). A big one is joining to another table via a custom field value, it completely breaks the underlying SQL. Otherwise, I love that extension and would use it once it's more mature. Until then, I just need something I can throw complex SQL at and allow a default sort field.